# How to run angular 6 app on local server via ip

Tags: angular6

I have angular 6 project & I have to implement social login so I need to specify ip  address of the server in google console. So is there any way to run angular 6 app via ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need this,

**STEP 1**
Go to System Preferences -> **`Network -> Wi-Fi`**

**STEP 2**
Copy the IP address below Status **`(Usually 192.168.1.x)`**

**STEP 3**
Paste it in your ng serve like:  **`ng serve --host 192.168.1.x`**